# Dynamic Columns in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to rewrite a CSV out using this code

```
Shared Sub ReadCSV()

        Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.csv")
        Dim lineQuery = From line In lines 
                        Let x = line.Split(New Char() {","}) 
                        Order By x(2) 
                        Select x(2) & ", " & x(1) & ", " & x(0)

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Out.csv ", lineQuery.ToArray())
    End Sub
```

As i want to vary the number of columns and their order ,How can i make this portion dynamic?

```
Select x(2) & ", " & x(1) & ", " & x(0)
```

I want to be able to select different number of columns and in different order

Comment: Why can't you use `Select x(2) & ", " & x(0) ` if you want those "
columns"?

Comment: This is intended to be used with CSV files by an end user , the number of columns would vary with CSV files and i would also like to vary the order.

Comment: You've gotten at least 3 good answers for this, why do you keep totally changing direction/approach?  You do not have to change the order of the data columns, just the order in which they are referenced when you output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first representing the columns you want to select as a list/array of indices and then using those to build your output. For example (sorry I'm mixing in C# here as I don't know VB):

```
// arbitrary set in different orders 
int[] columnsToSelect = new int[] { 3, 2, 1, 5 };

...


Select string.Join(", ", From i In columnsToSelect Select x(i));
```

`string.Join` let's you concatenate together an enumerable with a separator string. In this case, our enumerable is the columnsToSelect list with a Select projection to select out the ith index of the x array as each element.

Comment: this worked , However what this is Re-ordering all  the columns.
so if i want to make col1->col2 ; and col2->3 . it is basically moving col1 into the second position and then for the second step making it the third column

Comment: @Viladimir I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but yes my example shows a deliberate reordering. To keep columns in their native order, just keep columnsToSelect sorted and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following query which selects and orders only relevant columns from collections:

```
Dim selectColumns = {2, 1, 0}
Dim orderColumns = {0, 1}
Dim maxIndex = selectColumns.Union(orderColumns).Max()

Dim lines = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\test.csv")
            Let fields = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
            Select x = New With {.Line = line, .Fields = fields}
            Where x.Fields.Length > maxIndex
            Select x = New With {
                x.Line,
                .Fields = x.Fields.Where(Function(f, index) selectColumns.Contains(index)).ToArray()
            }
            Order By x.Fields(orderColumns(0)) ' presumes at least one order-column '
' Now order the rest of the columns with  Enumerable.ThenBy: '
For Each index As Int32 In orderColumns.Skip(1)
    Dim columnIndex As Int32 = index 'otherwise compiler complains about possible unexpected results(at least in .NET 4) '
    lines = lines.ThenBy(Function(x) x.Fields(columnIndex))
Next

Dim outLines = lines.Select(Function(x) String.Join(",", x.Fields)).ToList()
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Out.csv ", outLines)
```